# How to find where is 'uninitialized constant' called in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on Rails 6 and using devise and cancancan (and lots of other gems too).

When I call `User.find(id).destroy!` in rails console, it rollbacks with

```
NameError Exception: uninitialized constant User::Interactive
```

Also tried with byebug with the same result.

My head is spinning when I think about looking through all the files for the place where it is called.

I'd appreciate a clue ***how to track an uninitialized constant*** with less costs.

**UPDATE**
Already done by looking through gems.

UPDATE 2 - controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource
    #REST actions
end
```

Comment: Try to execute this, command from rails console.

Comment: could you show the controller for this

Comment: @Bhupati here you go

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to call this in IRB, which doesn't load your application.

Try running it in the rails console instead (`$ rails c`)

Comment: If that is the case...it's an issue with one of the gems you are using (since you did not create the class yourself)

Comment: Yes, I spent lots of time looking through'em. That's why I asked about smarter way.

Comment: Please post your Gemfile to your originial question

Answer (score 0):

so you should have controller like this.

```
class User::InteractiveController < ApplicationController

end
```